# How to fix "Method Not Allowed" error when trying to delete item with Angular and Spring Boot?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, rest

Why am I getting a "Whitelabel Error Page" with a "Method Not Allowed" status when trying to delete a student using a REST API built with Spring Boot and Angular? Here is my code:

student.component.ts:

```
deleteStudent(jmbag: string) : void {
    this.studentService.deleteStudent(jmbag);
}
```

student.service.ts:

```
deleteStudent(jmbag : string) : Observable<void> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/delete/${jmbag}`;
    console.log("Deleting. Url = " + url);
    return this.http.delete<void>(url);
}
```

StudentAPIController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
@AllArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class StudentAPIController {
    private StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<StudentDTO> getAllStudents(){
        return studentService.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Optional<Student> createStudent(@Valid @RequestBody Student student) {
        return studentService.createStudent(student);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{JMBAG}")
    public ResponseEntity<StudentDTO> deleteStudent(@PathVariable String JMBAG){
        boolean isStudentDeleted = studentService.deleteStudent(JMBAG);

        if(isStudentDeleted){
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to access the delete URL (e.g. "http://localhost:8080/api/delete/{JMBAG}") in the browser, I get the following error message:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Apr 16 17:46:26 CEST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Method 'GET' is not supported.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using Spring Security?

Comment: *Method 'GET' is not supported.* this is the key. for some reason, you are sending that as a GET request, not DELETE one.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `deleteStudent` method only via the DELETE HTTP method. The browser uses HTTP GET method only. I'd suggest using `Postman` or any other API testing tool where you can specify other HTTP methods than GET.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware that the browser uses HTTP GET method only and that the deleteStudent method can only be accessed via the DELETE HTTP method. However, I also found a solution to my problem. I added .subscribe() at the end of this.studentService.deleteStudent(jmbag) in student.component.ts, and it worked. Thanks again for your help!